# `docker-compose run --rm` does not remove depends_on services

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml file like this,

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  db-test:
    image: mariadb:10.6
    profiles:
      - test
  be:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: test.Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db-test
    volumes:
      - gradle-cache:/home/gradle/.gradle
    profiles:
      - test

# volumes
volumes:
  gradle-cache:
    driver: local
```

This is for testing the image inside a specific environment. This is a one time task; so I use `docker-compose run --profile test --rm be`.

This runs perfectly fine.

My concern is that, after the run is over, the dependency service `db-test` is still running. `be` service is automatically deleted when using `--rm` option.

Is there a way to clean up everything? i.e. containers related to `be` and `db-test` services must be deleted after the run is complete. Like in case of `docker-compose down`.

Answer (score 3):

As has been stated officially in an [issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2791) over at the official respository for docker compose, there is no way to use the `run` command along with the `--rm` flag  clean up dependant containers in one go. It will only shutdown and remove the container which is designated along with the flag.

And it seems there are no plans to fix what many would call an obvious flaw in the implementation of this command.

The suggested solution is to use a combination of `docker-compose run` and `docker-compose down` to achieve the desired behaviour. Something similar to this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: run.sh SERVICE [CMD...]

docker-compose run --rm "$@"
exit_code=$?
docker-compose down
exit $exit_code
```

Answer (score 0):

I think my answer is late for you but it can be pretty useful for others on the Internet.
You run your command with the profile option: `docker-compose run --profile test --rm be`. So when you want to delete all containers related to the profile, you need to run docker down with the profile option too: `docker-compose --profile test down`.